# PHP array get current element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an interesting task which can not handle. I have an PHP array that is generated automatically and randomly once a multi-dimensional, associative or mixed.

```
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player']['position']['hand']['name']['finalelement']
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player'][0]['position']['hand']['name']['finalelement']
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player'][0]['position']['hand']['name'][0]['finalelement']
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player']['position']['hand']['name'][0]['finalelement']
```

The goal is, no matter whether it is multidimensional or associative get to the final element. There is a simple way that has few if conditions. But I want to ask if you have an idea if there is any more intreresen way?

Comment: The deepest is always stored with finalelement key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) as follows :

```
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player']['position']['hand']['name']['finalelement'] = 'e1';
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player'][0]['position']['hand']['name']['finalelement'] = 'e2';
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player'][0]['position']['hand']['name'][0]['finalelement'] = 'e3';
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player']['position']['hand']['name'][0]['finalelement'] = 'e4';

$list = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, function ($value, $key) use (&$list) {
    $list[] = $value;
});

print_r($list);
```

This will Output the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => e1
    [1] => e4
    [2] => e2
    [3] => e3
)
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Next code returns first deepest value that is not an array:

```
$data['sport']['basketball']['team']['player']['position']['hand']['name'][0]['finalelement'] = 'end';

$current = $data;

while (is_array($current)) {
    $current = array_values($current)[0];
}

print $current; // end
```